# How to get all orderings of a list such that the list is equal to another list?

Tags: python, algorithm, list, sorting, permutation

I have lists A and B, which can have duplicates, for example:

```
A = ['x', 'x', 7]
B = [7, 'x', 'x']
```

Now I want all index permutations that permute list B into list A:

```
[1, 2, 0]    # because [B[1], B[2], B[0]] == A
[2, 1, 0]    # because [B[2], B[1], B[0]] == A
```

Is there are way to achieve this without iterating over all possible permutations?
I already use

```
import itertools
for p in itertools.permutations(range(len(B))):
    if A == permute(B,p):
```

to iterate over all possible permutations and check for the ones I want, but I want to have the right ones faster.

Comment: I'd recommed you to add tag "algorithm" to question.

Comment: Your question is very unclear.did you have tried any thing?

Comment: Are you just trying to find all the permutations of an array?

Comment: I'm very confused with the order `[b,a,a]` because you define a as two different values. `[0,1,2]`

Comment: You could use `xrange` instead of `range` for a possible performance gain.

Comment: Are there always going to be repeat values in your list?

Comment: @JGerulskis It's not different "values" it's different *indexes*.

Comment: @figs That's a strange question. Does it matter? I understand asking whether input will always be special, but not whether input will always *not* be special...

Comment: @Henri I rewrote your question a bit to make it clearer so the question hopefully gets reopened (and I can finally post my answer). Please check whether I did it right or changed the meaning of your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it. My `perms` function generates all valid permutations. First I collect the indexes for each element in B, then I recursively build and yield the permutations by always picking one of the still available indexes for each item in A until a permutation is ready to be yielded.

```
from collections import defaultdict

def perms(A, B):
    indexes = defaultdict(set)
    for i, e in enumerate(B):
        indexes[e].add(i)
    def find(perm):
        k = len(perm)
        if k == len(A):
            yield perm
            return
        I = indexes[A[k]]
        for i in list(I):
            I.remove(i)
            yield from find(perm + (i,))
            I.add(i)
    yield from find(())
```

Usage:

```
A = ['x', 'x', 7]
B = [7, 'x', 'x']

for perm in perms(A, B):
    print(perm)
```

Output:

```
(1, 2, 0)
(2, 1, 0)
```

Comment: Thank you, this works like a charm! Note: When using python 2.7: replace `yield from find(())` with `for p in find(()): yield p`

Answer (score 2):

You should decompose your problem in two :

- first find a particular permutation `sigma_0` that maps `B` onto `A`
- find the set `S_B` of all the permutations that map B onto itself

Then the set you are looking after is just `{sigma_0 \circ \sigma, sigma \in S_B}`.

Now the question becomes : how to we determine `S_B` ? To do this, you can just observe that if you write the set `{0,1,2,..,n}` (with `n=2`in your case) as `A_1 \cup .. A_k`, where each `A_i`corresponds to the indices in `B`that correspond to the i-th element (in your case, you would have `A_1 = {1,2}`and `A_2 = {0}`), then each element of `S_B` can be written in a unique manner as a product `tau_1 \circ .. tau_k`where each `tau_i` is a permutation that acts on `A_i`.

So, in your case `S_B = {id, (1,2)}` and you can take `sigma_0 = (0,2)`. It follows that the set your are after is `{(0,2), (2,0,1)}`.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in three steps. First, create a dictionary from list B that has items as keys and indexes as values. In your case, the dictionary for your list B:

```
B = [7, 'x', 'x']

  7 - [0]
'x' - [1, 2]
```

Then, go through your list A and build an index that maps List A indexes to their corresponding List B indexes. That is:

```
A = ['x', 'x', 7]

0 - [1, 2]
1 - [1, 2]
2 - [0]
```

From that, you can generate all of the valid mappings. It should be easy enough to write code that, given the index above, will generate `[1, 2, 0]` and `[2, 1, 0]`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's something in Python. I used strings for hashing since I'm not familiar with how to pass sets and arrays as recursive arguments in Python, although they might be more efficient.

```
A = ['x', 'x', 7, 'y', 8, 8]
B = [7, 'x', 8, 'x', 8, 'y']
H = {}

# record the indexes of elements in B
for i in xrange(0,len(B)):
  if B[i] in H:
    H[ B[i] ].append(str(i)) 
  else:
    H[ B[i] ] = [str(i)]

# build permutations in the order that the elements are encountered in A
def perms(perm,i,visited,l):
  if i==l:
    print perm
    return
  for j in H[ A[i] ]:
    if j not in visited:
      perms(perm + j,i + 1,visited + j,l)

perms("",0,"",len(A))
```

Output:

```
130524
130542
310524
310542
```